# malloc, free and redefinition of a variable

Tags: c, malloc, free, redefinition

I am trying to use a variable and erase it just after a function used it.
Basicacly I'm doint str1+str2, using it in a function and then freeing the memory.
I thought I got everything straigth but my code throw me warnings and an error:

1. ERROR: redefinition of 'commande'.
2. Warning: implicit declaration of function 'malloc' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
3. Warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'malloc' [enabled by default]
4. Warning: implicit declaration of function 'free' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
5. Warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'free' [enabled by default]

Here is the aforementioned code:

```
// Step 1
char* commande = (char*) malloc(len1 + len2 + 1);
strcpy(commande, str1);
strcat(commande, str2);
function(commande);
free(commande);
// Step 2
char* commande = (char*) malloc(len3 + len4 + 1);
strcpy(commande, str3);
strcat(commande, str4);
function(commande);
free(commande);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I corrected the typo in len2.

Comment: you've defined `commande` twice and you have not included the header for malloc/free (probably stdlib.h)

Comment: len1 + len4 is a heap corruption waiting to happen.

Comment: avoid casting (char*) with malloc: char* commande = malloc(len1 + len4 + 1);

Comment: when I need dynamic strings, I usually use utstring, a useful set of string macros to do beautiful things with strings: http://uthash.sourceforge.net/utstring.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A statement such as

```
char* commande = (char*) malloc(len3 + len4 + 1);
```

is a variable *declaration*. It says the compiler: I want commande to be a pointer to a character. You can declare variables only once in a function, as it wouldn't make any sense to redeclare a variable.

The errors about incompatible implicit definitions come from the fact that you didn't tell the compiler what type `malloc` has. To do that, you have to include a *header file* that contains all neccessary declarations. Place the following line on top of your file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've included  and there is no need to declare the pointer commande after line2.